# Default UICollectionView layout not respecting iPad split screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uisplitviewcontroller

My layout when on split screen is not respecting the width of the split screen.

My custom view is respecting it(the black bar at the top) but anything using autolayout is not respecting the width.

I am handling rotation using

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
```

Is there a helper method for handling split view? Do I handle it in `layoutSubview`? I would have expected the UICollectionView to handle this for us.

In viewWillTransition I use

```
  guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
            return
        }

  flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "default" layout you mean a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  It looks like the itemSize width is bigger then the width of the view.  Try adding a check in  `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to make sure that the width is less than or equal to the collection's width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That issue still exist in iOS 13 beta 7.

If you implement multiple-window and split two collection view side by side. The only left window will layout correct (rotate several times could see that).

[image]

Add that in view controller can fix it:

```swift
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```